# Creating a P2P hosted website

Tags: web-hosting, p2p

Is there a way to create a peer-to-peer hosted website securely:
- Without Having a connection between the developer (host) of the website to the website?
- Securing some information the site uses like a database that shouldn't be plainly view-able by the "peer hoster".
- Having the website still run code (eg. possibly selecting from the decentralized db)

I'm asking this because I think this could be a solution for creating a website in a closed monitored network (1000s of PCs) without making it clear on who is the host of the website is.

Is there any current solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

[FreeNet](https://freenetproject.org/) is a distributed p2p network that relies upon a [Distributed Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table) to store and distribute data. One of the hallmarks of this network is that once a page is pushed to FreeNet,  it can't removed (as long as people are viewing the content).

However,  it sounds like a [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) mash-up is what your looking for.

Comment: I don't believe FreeNet would allow for the website to run code

Comment: @Jeremy French Yes,  the website is free to run JavaScript and use localstorage. A server-side web application would require Tor.

Comment: How would you start such a project with TOR? and in an a closed network?